# Dreamweaver's Code Editor, highlight

Tags: ide, dreamweaver

I am new to Dreamweaver (and Mac). I am used to using notepad++. I am in the habit of highlighting a term, and having identical terms highlighted everywhere in the current document. Can this be done with Dreamweaver? If it is not possible to do this with Dreamweaver, then what code editor will do this on a Mac?

Comment: I downloaded Komodo edit. While it does not automatically highlight all words highlighted by cursor, following this with a simple 'cmd-f' does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/.
Or maybe try using eclipse, it might be a bit of overkill, but then again I have no idea what are doing in the dreamweaver.

Comment: I will consider it (/look into it). Lightweight is generally better. Syntaxes include java, php, javascript and html. I have considered Aptana Studio, but I really miss the lightweight, does-all qualities of notepad++.

Comment: I heard Komodo Edit is pretty good too. I actually never tried either one of these, except for Eclipse. So, good luck! As far as Komodo, i heard lots of good things from several people. Hope it helps.

Comment: Anyone know for certain if Komodo Edit OR textwrangler will highlight identical terms as mentioned in the original question?